# Outlook blocking ip using spamhaus despite server not being on list

Tags: email, smtp, email-filter

#### 2023-09-05

1. Reply to email from example.com
2. Receive response:

> to=person@example.com, relay=example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com[52.101.68.18]:25, delay=6.5, delays=6.1/0.02/0.35/0.03, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host reply-com.mail.protection.outlook.com[52.101.68.18] said: 550 5.7.1 Service unavailable, Client host [MY_IP] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/MY_IP AS(1450) (in reply to RCPT TO command))

3. Successfully request removal from spamhaus
4. Wait 1 hour
5. Re-send email
6. Same response (spamhaus query says no issues now)

#### 2023-09-08

1. Re-send email
2. Same response (spamhaus query still says no issues)
3. Request aid on superuser

Comment: My experience with Spamhaus is that is very difficult to remove a blacklist off their site. I have no suggestions except to keep trying.  It is so difficult my ISP changed my IP here rather than fight with Spamhaus.

Comment: According to the spamhaus query, there are no issues with my IP address anymore having requested removal on Tuesday. The removal appeared to be instant on their end and I've allowed multiple days for outlook's servers to update but they just seem to still have the old data.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with you. Merely that the left hand of Spamhaus removes something, and the right hand ignores that.

Comment: Ah I see, so outlook is just ignoring removals... Such a pity